# Is it bad practice to return a Data structure of member functions in composition?

Tags: oop, composition

Take for example you have a class A and class B. Class A uses a compositional type relationship that interacts with many of the class B objects. class A stored these class B objects references in  an Arralist

```
Class A
{
    ArrayList<B> beeObjects;
}
```

Is it bad practice to return the Array list data structure if you wanted to implement functionality that interacts with the objects in the arraylist?

Comment: No, In-fact oops work in the form of object. It should not considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Not at all.** You can very well return your `ArrayList` beeObjects and use it. In fact, in Object Orient Programming, you would like to do as normal practice provided you have genuine usage scenario.

Comment: And its proper too, instead to copy it into some other location then use at returned location